# Call third party module block in CMS page in magento 2

Tags: module, cms-pages, custom-block, magento2.2

Is there any way to insert custom block in CMS page in **Magento 2.2** alike inserting CMS block in CMS page?

Comment: You can call phtml file in cms page that contains specific block...Do u asking like this?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right about custom block (template.phtml), you need to create custom template in (for example) `app/code/<Package>/<Module>/view/frontend/templates/cms/customTemplate.phtml` and then insert this template in a CMS Page via layout update (in admin panel):

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="your.custom.name" template="<Package>_<Module>::cms/customTemplate.phtml" before="-" />
</referenceContainer>
```